# How to reduce output in `docker-compose` up command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration

I'm looking for a way to reduce the output generated by `docker compose up`.
When running in CI all the "interactive" output for download and extract progress is completely useless and generate lots of useless text.

`docker` has `--quiet` but I don't see the same for `docker compose`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a `--quiet-pull` option that lets you reduce the output generated `docker compose up` and `docker compose run`

> `docker compose up --quiet-pull`

Answer (score 3):

You can always run the docker compose in a detached mode with the `-d` parameter and then check logs of the service/container you want with `docker logs --follow <container>`

There was an option to set the log-level with `--log-level [DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL]` but it is deprecated from version 2.0.